# not able to launch the application on Samsung 4.0.4 devices

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am working on an application. In project.properties file, i was using target=android-9

Recently to use the DragEvent , i had updated target=android-17

After that i can install the app on device with Android 4.0.4. But i cannot launch the application.

When i click on the app, i just does not launch.

I dont know why i cannot launch on devices with 4.0.4 version.

Is there any mistake i am doing by updagrading the target=android-17

Inside the manifsest file i have given

Please guide me to know why i cannot launch my app on devices with Android 4.0 version

1. Is it some mistake that i cannot launch my app on older 4.0.4 versions?
2. Sometimes my code log shows

   *Native code library failed to load.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:   165 cannot locate 'log2'...*

is it some hidden issues in Android 4.0.4? or is it that i compiled using a higher api version 17 .

Answer (score 1):

THe crash you show is a missing native library call.  That has nothing to do with your target change.  Your target change is a problem though-  4.0.4 devices do not have v17 functions, no matter what your target is.  If you put it on those devices without an if statement preventing executing those functions, the device will crash when you call them.  If you want to run on 4.0.4, you can't use any function introduced after v14, unless you get it via the support library.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `jni/Application.mk` (or if you already have it, change/add this line in it instead) and add the following line:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

This makes sure that the native code is built targeting `android-9` even if you have a different target for the java code. As long as you don't need features from `android-17` in the native code, this should work just fine.